# AKS cluster find Azure CNI version

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, cni

I have an Azure AKS Cluster which utilizes the Azure CNI Network plugin.

How can I find the CNI version being used in this cluster?

I want find out if my AKS Cluster used the traditional Azure CNI v1 or Azure CNIv2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [this document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-container-networking/blob/master/docs/cni.md) you can do:

```
/opt/cni/bin/azure-vnet --version
```

on your node(s). that can be easily done with `kubectl debug`